# Find number of files in each directory in a tree of directories

Tags: linux, perl, sed, find

I need to find out what directories in a tree have the most files in them (but not in their subdirectories). Directories should not be counted.

This is easily soluble with bash, Perl, Python, Tcl, etc. but it is interesting to solve it as one-liner.

I wrote the following one-liner that counts correctly

`ls -Rp1 | grep -vP '\/$' | perl -pe 's/\n/ /' | perl -e '$ln=<>;@ds=split/(?=\.\/)/,$ln;for(@ds){($d,$fs)=split/:/;$fs=~s/^\s+|\s+$//;$c=split/\s+/,$fs;$fc+=$c;print "$c $d\n"}print "Totals: dirs: @{[scalar @ds]}, files: $fc\n"' | sort -n`

Is there a more elegant one-line solution to do this, not necessarily with Perl?

This is the multi-line equivalent

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$line = <>;
@dirs = split/(?=\.\/)/, $line;

for ( @dirs ) {
    ($dir, $files) = split /:/;
    $files =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//;
    $count = split/\s+/, $files;
    $total_files_count += $count;
    print "$count $dir\n"
}

print "Totals: dirs: @{[scalar @dirs]}, files: $total_files_count\n";
```

Comment: So you need a total count of _files_ (not subdirs) for each directory, with all of its subdirectories, from the top-level of your hierarchy?  (Or count of files in each directory, recursively?)

Comment: I need a count of files in every directory within the given directory tree. Not a count of files in directory and all of its subdirectories - this wouldn't help to find directories with largest amount of files.

Comment: Your question should contain only information that is relevant to the problem. If you want to comment on an answer then you should add a comment beneath that answer.

Comment: @Borodin just for your information: your editing **completely** changed the meaning of my question. So now the question not only lost some useful code (that **is** relevant to the question), but neither the marked answer, nor my initial example don't answer the question anymore, doing something **entirely** else. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jcaron: Your comment is clearly not *"just for [my] information"* and sarcasm is unnecessarily vulgar. I tried to clarify your question as I found it difficult to understand. If I got it wrong then I apologise, but the only code I removed should have been part of a comment on an answer and didn't add to the question at all. Please explain how I misrepresented your question so that I can fix it.

Comment: @Borodin First, I'm not jcaron. Second, **3 men** here managed to understand the question correctly and posted relevant answers from which I chose the best in my opinion. There is a clarification in the 2nd comment here. I don't know how to improve further. I even can't imagine how "count files" may be interpreted as "count subdirectories". It was in original subject and body of the question. Third, I put the variations of the answer just to be easily available to any other without reading comments. I honestly don't get what is bad about it.

Comment: @Borodin Ok, I've edited the question to restore its original meaning. Hopefully you'll find it acceptable. Sorry for sarcasm, but the experience was a bit frustrating, and I'm just a human being. Honestly, I think you could read the original question more thoroughly before editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn’t this work?

```
find . -type f | sed -e 's/[^\\/]*$//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10
```

PS: you may want to post the challenge to code golf if the intent is the shortest code.

Comment: Oh, this is really promising! I'll play with it a little and give you a feedback.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot! Can't imagine that there may be significantly shorter solution except a tool for such task. Anyway, I'd like to give this a little more time before marking your solution with 'answered'.

Comment: Perl equivalent (your solution still shorter):
`find . -type f | perl -pe 's|[^/]*$|\n|' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

Comment: In your solution we don't have to use slashes in sed. This also works:
`find . -type f | sed -e 's|[^/]*$||' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: Replaced `sed` by `find`'s `-printf`. Also, we don't really need to specify period in `find` for current directory:
`find -type f -printf "%h\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

Comment: The text of my question has been heavily edited, and not only completely lost its initial meaning, but also all the variations of your answer. It will be very nice if you could add to your answer the command with `-printf` so it will be easily available to anyone without digging in comments. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice work. One could save a few more characters by replacing the sed with **xargs -i dirname "{}"** ;}

Comment: @tink that was my first attempt, but it’s a lot less efficient, spawning `dirname` for each file.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

countFiles($ARGV[0]);

sub countFiles() {
        my $dir=shift;
        my @list=glob("$dir/*");
        my $count=0;
        for (@list) {
                if (-d) {
                        countFiles($_);
                }
                else {
                        $count++;
                }
        }
        print "directory=$dir, file count=$count\n";
}
```

Or a one liner

```
find . -type f | perl -e 'while(<ARGV>){chomp;s/(.*\/).*$/\1/; $hash{$_}++;}for(keys %hash){print "$_ count=$hash{$_}\n";}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the answer to my question. I mentioned that this task is easily solvable by scripting. I'd like to know if there is any more elegant one-liner than mine or some existing linux cli tool for this task.

Comment: see the update, if you find all the files, strip of the filenames and count the directories.

Comment: OK, this is much more elegant than my solution. I made a minor change by placing count before directory name to be able to sort the results easily:
`find . -type f | perl -e 'while(<ARGV>){chomp;s/(.*\/).*$/\1/; $hash{$_}++;}for(keys %hash){print "$hash{$_} $_\n";}' | sort -n`
The problem is that this solution counts 1 file in empty directories (not ok) and also 1 file in directories that have only 1 file (ok).

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it just don't list empty directories!

Comment: Anyway, isn't there any shorter way to do this? Possibly not with Perl. Maybe with awk, sed, whatever...

Comment: Interesting problem, you need to strip of the filename to leave the directory, which you could do with sed, but then you have to do the counting in either perl or awk, so it's as broad as it's long :)

Comment: Actually, I think that giving up on empty directories is ok in this case as I don't want to find what directories are empty.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl "one"-liner, using core (and efficient) [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)

```
perl -MFile::Find -wE'
    find({no_chdir=>1, wanted => sub { ++$dc{$File::Find::dir} if -f }}, "."); 
    printf "%4d => $_\n", $dc{$_} for sort { $dc{$b} <=> $dc{$a} } keys %dc;
'
```

printing (correct) counts of "plain" files ([`-f`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)) in each directory (and not its subdirectories)

```
  45 => .
   7 => ./dir/sub_dir_1
   4 => ./dir
   3 => ./another_dir
   2 => ./dir/sub_dir_2
```

Or with [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) which has a nicer interface, and with a different output format

```
perl -MList::Util=max -MFile::Find::Rule -wE'
    @dirs   = File::Find::Rule->directory->in(".");
    $dc{$_} = File::Find::Rule->file->maxdepth(1)->in($_) for @dirs;
    @skeys = sort { $dc{$b} <=> $dc{$a} } keys %dc;
    $ml = max map { length } @skeys; 
    for (@skeys) { printf "%${ml}s => $dc{$_}\n", $_ }
'
```

The last three lines and `-MList::Util=max` are there only for output format. Prints

```
            . => 47
dir/sub_dir_1 => 7
          dir => 4
  another_dir => 3
dir/sub_dir_2 => 2
    empty_dir => 0
```

---